# How to test swift-playground with AR on Mac if I don't have iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, swift-playground, wwdc

I wanna make AR app for WWDC Scholarship 2020. And the problem that I dont have IPad to test works AR or not in playground. How I can test my playground project on my mac?

Comment: You will really need an AR capable device to test an AR project I'm afraid

Comment: You know how I can test it on my IPhone? Because it's no button "build" in playground

Comment: I think you will need to test your code using Xcode so you can build it to your phone. You can then copy it to a playground to submit it.

Comment: You Genius! Sorry for my Stupid 

Comment: I also am making a Swift Playground with ARKit but just want to let you know that some things are different on app vs on playground. I personally wouldn’t create an ARKit playground if you don’t have an iPad to test it on for the fear of the playground not working.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode Simulator still doesn't support AR apps (nor Xcode Playground). The only way you can run or test your AR app is to compile it for iOS/iPadOS device. Also you can use Swift Playgrounds for iPad.